# Mostrar registro dependiendo de columna - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi consulta es quiero mostrar mi registro cuando la columna estado cambie todo en pagado. Si la columna estado me muestra en pago y en pendiente que no me muestre nada. Todo es en sql server. 
¿Como seria en codigo transact sql?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es saber la información de pago cuando su estado es pagado

Prueba el siguiente código.

```
  select * from [nombre_tabla] where estado='PAGADO'
```

Comment: PERO QUIERO AGRUPARLO. QUE ME MUESTRE EL REGISTRO CUANDO LA COLUMNA ESTADO SEA PAGADO

Comment: con el codigo que he puesto te tienen que salir todos los registros que tengan el valor 'pagado' en la columna 'estado', de nbo ser así, ¿Qué te sale?